# Clear Contents in Sheet1 based on a date in Sheet2

Tags: vba

Short question. I have one excel file with two sheets (Sheet1, Sheet2). On sheet1 column A i have a list of dates, on column D i have some numbers. On sheet2 A16, i have a date.

I would like to be able to delete the numbers on Sheet1 column D, starting from a date found in  sheet2 cell A16. The date in Sheet2!A16 will change everyday, so i will delete numbers starting from different dates... 

**sheet 1 image**
[image]

**sheet 2 image**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
Sub UpdateColD()
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet
  Dim strDate As String
  Dim lngLastRow As Long
  Dim lngDateRow As Long

  Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

  'Find the last row in column D - we will clear all cells until and including this row
  lngLastRow = ws1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  ' Get Date - careful with formatting and types, I've used a string
  strDate = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(16, 1)

  ' Iterate over all rows until you find the value
  For r = 1 To lngLastRow
    If ws1.Cells(r, 1) = strDate Then
        lngDateRow = r
        Exit For
    End If
  Next r

  ' Only clear if the date was found
  If lngDateRow > 0 Then
      ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(lngDateRow + 1, 4), ws1.Cells(lngLastRow, 4)).Clear
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you step into the code and see what happens? I made the assumption that the worksheets were called "Sheet1" and "Sheet2". Worked for me in my recreation of the workbook so it's just a matter of finding the difference ;)

Comment: I will try again, of course. Yes, sheets are named "Sheet1" and "Sheet2". First time i didn't have any error. But nothing happend.. :)) First time when i tought about this solution it i tought it will be very easy. Now i'm stuck :) So, just find the date in Sheet2!A16, find this date in Sheet1! Column A, delete de entire column D, starting from the date in Sheet2!A16. I will try again and let you know. Thank you very much pwwolff !

Comment: This is my test file:   https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9tH3lTneqQUWldwRU9xdmpIYmc

Comment: The value in sheet2 A16 is 15/01/17. That value isn't present in the list in sheet1 so it doesn't find the value and doesn't clear anything ;). Try running the code and stepping through one line at at time by hitting f8

Comment: Also, try changing the value in A16 to 15/10/17. It works ;)

Comment: Omg, i'm so stupid. I just saw that i wroted october in Sheet1 and january in sheet2  :)) Thank you so much for your patience, mate!

Comment: If i am not asking to much, is there any chance you could help me import the numbers from sheet2 column D, into sheet1, column D, starting from 15.01.2017? :)

Comment: I finally succeeded to import the numbers from sheet2, into sheet1. The problem is that in sheet2 i have another column (column E)  and it's importing the dates from column D and E. How can i import only from column D?

Comment: Done! Thank you again pwwolff, for everything!